# In the quest "Diplomatic Immunity", how do I get past the Thalmor Soldiers with the disguise on?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

They keep saying "Come here, let me see your face." and "Haven't seen him around before." and there's also a guy by the door whom I can't just bypass. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those words just depend on your race. If you're a High Elf, go out the door to the guard and tell him Elewen needs him. But I know you aren't a High Elf because of the way the Thalmor soldiers say it.

Here are the dialogues of Thalmor depending on race.

High Elf: Must be new around here.

Wood Elf: Seems a bit short to me.

Human/Dark Elf/Orc: You there. I don't think I've seen you around before." or "Come here. Let me see your face." or "Haven't seen him/her around before." or "Must be new around here [This must be one of the races you're using].

Beast [Khajiit or Argonian]: Wait, is that a tail?

If you're an Altmer, you can tell the Wizard at the door to talk to Elenwen. You must use Speech. If you fail, the courtyard will be hostile.

[Source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Diplomatic_Immunity)

Comment: I'm an imperial, so there's no way to do the disguise mission at all in covert? I have to kill them?

Comment: @user400424 as said, you can't persuade the thalmor at the front of the Solar to talk to Elenwen if you're not a High Elf.

Comment: I don't know how many times I've beaten Skryim, but I had no idea there was a way to get to the solar in disguise. Learn something new every day.

Comment: @DCShannon yeah.